# How to implement a store locator?

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to create with something similar to [this store locator](http://www.starbucks.com/store-locator) using Drupal?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

Another option is the recently released [Google Store Locator](http://drupal.org/project/google_store_locator) module on drupal.org. Some cool features: you can customize the map marker pins to be your own custom icon, and you can make the map 'location aware' which allows the user to share their location with the browser, and the map will re-center and zoom based on their location.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it will be complex to set up.  If you're using Drupal 7, you can create a "Store" content type with checkbox fields that store the various attributes (24-hour service, airport locations, etc.)

Then you can install the [location](http://drupal.org/project/location) module to assign a location to each store.  You will need to enable the feature for converting the addresses you input into latitudes and longitudes.

Next, installing the [gmap](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) module will give you the ability to display Google maps.

For the search functionality, you can use [views](http://drupal.org/project/views), for which there are many excellent tutorials online.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [OpenLayers locator](http://drupal.org/project/ol_locator) that was just released, and that I maintain. It is a feature module that creates a robust, turn-key store locator using the Openlayers, Openlayers Proximity, Addressfield, Geofield and Geocoder modules.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [IP Geolocation Views & Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) module. Partial quote from its project page:

> Despite what the name may suggest, IP Geolocation Views & Maps (IPGV&M) is first and foremost a mapping engine.
>
> The module makes it very easy to create Views-based mapping solutions using the map renderer of your choice (**Google**, **OpenLayers** or **Leaflet**) with any location storage module of your choice, e.g.:
>
> - [Get Locations](http://drupal.org/project/getlocations),
> - [Geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield),
> - [Geolocation Field](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation)
> - [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location).

[image]

> This allows you to bring together modules and feature sets that without IPGV&M you would not be able to combine.
>
> Like beautiful animated [marker clustering on Google or Bing or Mapbox ...](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_markercluster) any of various [map providers](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_more_maps).
>
> But more importantly IPGV&M adds some features you won't find as conveniently packaged elsewhere.
>
> These include [marker differentiation based on field values or ranges](http://flink.com.au/ramblings/spruce-your-map-markers-font-icons) (2nd screenshot) with or without font icons, various centering options, super-imposing the current visitor's location, allowing multiple content types to be displayed on the same map, full screen button and mini-map inset (bottom screenshot), polygon support (Geofield), marker tags and tool tips and cross-highlighting of associated content on the page when markers are hovered (and vice versa).

[image]

Head over to its (impressive) project page for even more information about it (it would be way too long to include a quote of it all here). That project page also includes various screenshots.

Comment: Hello Pierre,
Thanks for sharing details.
Can you guide to achieve same in Drupal 8?

Comment: Hey @parth.k , not that i do not want, but I'm not aware (yet) of how to do this in D8. D8 (core) is great, but for as long a there are no mature versions of modules like this one (and the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, etc), I find it pretty much a waste of time to try to build D8 sites ... unless you have an unlimited budget to build your own, custom, modules. Maybe you should just post a D8 related question about what you're trying to get to work?