# Create a hospital locator in drupal 7

Tags: 7, location, google-maps

I want to have a page in my site where the logged in user can look for hospitals, clinics and pharmacies near to him.

I want these information to be shown on a map, preferably Google maps. I came to know about [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location) module, but I dont know whether I can accomplish what I want to accomplish using it.

The map should only show hospitals, clinics and pharmacies around the user's location (withing a 30 km radius for example).

What's the right way to go to get this done?

What reported in [How to implement a store locator?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25855/store-locator-module) does look similar to what am planning, but in their case they have kind of plotted all their stores on the map and they have displayed the ones near to the user. In my case, I want users to be able to search for hospitals and such places (it doesn't matter what hospital it is) or see those places close to their current position. I want to get something similar to what shown in the following screeshot, which is showing all the dental clinics in Bangalore. How can I get this functionality?

[image: screenshot]

I have tried, [OpenLayers Locator](http://drupal.org/project/ol_locator) as suggested by nicoz. So far I have been able to get the below result.

[image: screenshot]

I created a content called 'Location' which takes the address while creating. Using the Views module, I am displaying that address on a map. That's not what I want: I want the users to be able to search for it.
I am also not getting that proximity option. What customizations should I have to achieve this? I don't know what to change, and where. I am getting the following error on the module page:

> Error making request to server.

[image: screenshot]

I am getting some AJAX errors when I try to edit views (especially 'page' option).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store locator module?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25855/store-locator-module)

Comment: Well, it does look a little similar, but in that graph, they have plotted all their store addresses in their an the map is shown. In my case, I want users to be able to search for it or by default when they visit that page, the map should be showing all those places.

Comment: I built the OpenLayers Locator module and it does exactly what you are describing. All views can be searched for locations within a configurable distance of a provided postal code, city, province, state or any other geo-spatial reference point understood by Google.  It also built on views, so you can customize it further to what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I can use it as I needed, it would really great. But am not finding a detailed documentation on how to achieve it. Am not very experienced in drupal, so I would need a little more explanation than that is provided on the project page. Can you help me with that..??

Comment: I am not sure what more to tell you. The module does exactly what you want right out of the box. Install it and go. You may just have to add a taxonomy select field to the Location content type that specifies "hospital, clinic or pharmacy". Then add that field to the default view and expose it for your users.

Comment: So... I will definitely try that. If am faced with any problem, can I contact you..? The main thing am concerned is that am not that familiar with views...:(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2831/discussion-between-nicoz-and-akshaynhegde)