# How to iterate through Drupal.settings in a js file when there are lots of variables?

Tags: 7, javascript

Am trying to create a health service locator using Google maps API on my Drupal 7 site. (FYI, I cant use location module or open layers, because, [Create a hospital locator in drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25874/create-a-hospital-locator-in-drupal-7)  )

OK, so now I have a form, which takes the users location, type of service (eg, hospital, pharmacy etc) and the proximity around which they wish to find the result, using [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) and [Google Places API](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/&ei=bbl1T-CHDMWGrAfQnIiVDQ&usg=AFQjCNEV603kicx-vghMMa16__ZJsyA2dQ&sig2=N7bMDLFvDgYqEOJcmYByYw&cad=rja) I fetch the results (details about those near by places such as hospital) in JSON format from Google. The fetched data includes each place's name, address, rating, phone number, latitude, longitude etc. now I store those values in `form_state['storage']` and then sends it to the JS file using the `drupal_add_js()` method.

The below code is sending the values,

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)
 {
  drupal_add_js(array('a'.$i =>array(
             'lat'=> $form_state['storage']['results'][$i]['geometry']['location']['lat'],
             'long'=> $form_state['storage']['results'][$i]['geometry']['location']['long'],  
         'name'=>  $form_state['storage']['results'][$i]['name'],
         'rating'=>$form_state['storage']['results'][$i]['rating'],
         'vicinity'=>$form_state['storage']['results'][$i]['vicinity'],
         'formatted_address'=>$form_state['storage']['results'][$i]['formatted_address'],
         'international_phone_number'=>$form_state['storage']['results'][$i]['international_phone_number'],
         'website'=>$form_state['storage']['results'][$i]['website'],
)),'setting');

}
?>.
```

the details of first place is in a0, second place detail is in a1 etc.

FYI, each place details are in `Drupal.settings.a0`, `Drupal.settings.a1`  etc.
 I mean, I can access those variables in js file using,

`Drupal.settings.a0.name` and `Drupal.settings.a0.website`
similarly for second place, `Drupal.settings.a1.name` etc.

Now my problem is I need to iterate through these different places.

I can iterate through different variables of one particular place usin the below for loop,

```
for(var x in Drupal.settings.a0)
{
 alert(Drupal.settings.a0.x);
}
```

But, I cant iterate through different places, like a0, a1 etc.
I mean I cant attach a variable to drupal.settings..!

I tried tried putting all places in an array, i.e, a0,a1,a2 are in an array named `arr[]` (I have the total no. of places in `Drupal.settings.my_vars.length`) then, I iterate through this array and tried attaching arr[i] to `Drupal.settings` as `Drupal.settings.arr[i].x` but it doesn't work.

How can I do it...?? Is there any better way of achieving it...??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First your array should be added in your module's namespace (`$your_array = array('yourmodule' => $your_array);` and then `drupal_add_js` as usual). Then, I don't see what could prevent you from looping in your `Drupal.settings.yourmodule` array, for example with [JQuery $_each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Comment: you are right, but in my case, I have many "yourmodule" kind of arrays, i.e, a0, a1 etc. I need to know how can I iterate through these.

Comment: If you add your arrays the way I told above, you have to do something like : `$.each(Drupal.settings.yourmodule, function(location) {do_something(location.name);});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer...! The below code works..!

```
var i = 0, j=0;
while(Drupal.settings["a" + i])
{
  for(j in Drupal.settings["a" + i])
  {
    if(Drupal.settings["a" + i].hasOwnProperty(j))
    {
      alert(Drupal.settings["a" + i][j]);
    }
  }
  i++;
}
```

But **I would like know what exactly is hasOwnProperty(j)**...?? (I got this answer in drupal forum)

Comment: hasOwnProperty means it's a property not inherited from the base object, this is to make sure it's a property added to to object directly. Full explanation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty

Answer (score 2):

You can add your module name to settings like this

```
$locations = array();
for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  $locations[] = array('a'.$i =>array(
    'lat'=> $form_state['storage']['results'][$i]['geometry']['location']['lat'],
    'long'=> $form_state['storage']['results'][$i]['geometry']['location']['long'],  
  );
}

drupal_add_js(array('mymodule' => $locations), 'setting');
```

and loop is js like

```
for (var x in Drupal.settings.mymodule) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: how can I access the location of 1st place , 2nd lace etc..?? each place will have its own set of locations, name,address etc. Can you please explain your answer a little bit more..?

Comment: so you'll have an array of places and each place has one or more locations, so you have to use a nested loop, use something like $locations[$placename][] on line 3 i the example above, and on the js side something like: for (var place in Drupal.settings.mymodule) {  for (var location in place) {